# How to set the first entry in treemap in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections

I have list of key and value pair in that i need one item to come in front. Eg :100 different type of fruits and fruitcode, i will sort alphabetically and put in JSON, i need to bring orange to be front so the order will be Orage,Apple,Banana .. etc. Is this possible

```
Iterator itr = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while ( itr.hasNext() )
            {
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) itr.next();
                String fruit_type="Orange";
                 if(fruit_type.equals(me.getValue())){
                     itr.remove();
                    }
                JSONObject frtObj = new JSONObject();

                frtObj.put("fruitCode", me.getValue());
                frtObj.put("fruitName", me.getKey());
                frtArrayObj.add(frtObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just put some entry as first entry in treemap. There is another way way to achieve it, while creating the TreeMap pass custom `Comaparator`.

And in the `Comparator<? super K> comparator` write a logic that Orange should come in first element. It ensure you that "Orange" would be always first element of the map.

Code snippet :

```
Comparator<String> customComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            // Add null check
            if(s1.equals("Orange"))
               return 1; 
            else if(s2.equals("Orange"))
               return -1;
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }           
    };
```

...

```
SortedMap<String,String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>(customComparator );
```

Comment: here s1 and s2 is key and value ?